# How to recursively get records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have entity called posts in my app. Posts can be children of other posts, so that parent post has hasMany('posts') and children have hasOne('post') the inclusion is infinite.

Here is the schema:

[image]

How can I recursively get all children and children of children and etc. of the first Post that has 'post_id' set to null?

Please don't comment about performance here, I do know that such a schema is bad, what I want to know is only how to correctly write the recursive function to retrieve the infinite nested posts.

For instance lets say, I have the first post 1. 
Post 2 and 3 are children of post 1. 
Post 4 and 5 are children of post 2. 
Post 6 and 7 are children of post 3. 
Post 8,9,10 are children of post 5. 
Post 11,12,13 are children of post 7. 
Post 14 is children of post 10. 
I want to write a recursive function that will get me posts 2-14. 
[image]

Comment: This logic design doesn't seem very thought out. May I ask *why* such a deep embedding of posts? On Facebook, they deep embed as far as 2 on a parent post (Parent -> comment -> comment on comment)

Comment: Its not correct you have to use hasMany in that case since post 1 has 2 kids.

Comment: @Derek please forget about why it is so, and the performance. It is not the case here. The most important for me is writing the recursive function. Concerning the schema it is not a real use case.

Comment: For something really efficient, you should probably have 2 fields in your DB, `parent_post` and `sub_parent_post` - the first would be the top level post ID for which it belongs to, and the second would be its immediate post parent

Comment: Then simply query all posts with the `parent_post` and then process the `sub_parent_post` in either your PHP or javascript

Comment: @Derek I do know that already. I have asked one time in the post and asking again in the comment - do not ask about the schema and performance. My question is pretty clear.

Comment: Show what you have tried and why it doesn't work.  Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @Kyslik the Post model has both hasMany and hasOne. hasOne to retrieve the parent and hasMany to retrieve the children and both methods work.

Comment: I doubt anyone will answer this considering the security and efficiency implications. Stack Overflow isn't a place where bad practices are flourished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specifically asked us not to comment about performance you should just add a `with` attribute on the post model to include all children eagerly.

```
class Post extends Model
{

   protected $with = [
        'posts'
   ];

   public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that what I was searching for.